# Which mechanical system has a Moebius strip as its configuration space?

Tags: classical-mechanics, topology

- A harmonic oscillator has a line as its configuration space.
- A pendulum has a circle as its configuration space.
- *Which system has a Moebius strip as its configuration space?*

Comment: A particle confined to a Moebius strip?

Comment: I really do not see any difference between an harmonic oscillator and a pendulum (for small oscillations).

Comment: @sintetico That's because you're restricting yourself to small oscillations. :P

Comment: does there has to be one?